# Is Whitespace a token in Java?

Tags: java, token

Is this true? Are whitespaces considered a token in Java?
**This picture is taken from W3 schools website.**

[image]

Comment: Huh? `publicstaticinta` is a weirdly named identifier. What are you getting at?

Comment: I would love to know why they say that because whitespace isn't traditionally considered a token. It smells like classic w3schools garbage.

Comment: There are reasons why that site is often called `w3fools`.

Comment: [Java Language Specification #3.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.5): 'Those input elements that are *not* white space or comments are tokens. The tokens are the terminal symbols of the syntactic grammar (§2.3).' Emphasis added.

Comment: @user207421 That should be an answer.  I don't think we can get any more of a definitive answer than the JLS itself.

Comment: There is plenty of other nonsense at that site, and I cited some of it, and several people upvoted the comment, but SO moderators are busily removing statements of fact from here, which I can't do anything about, and I'm not going to repeat the research. Just avoid the site.

Answer (score 2):

No, as said in the comments, whitespaces aren't considered tokens in Java. This can only be an error in the documentation of W3 schools that should be corrected.